# slick mysql streaming to avoid GC and OOM issues

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

While querying records from DB for a specified date range I am getting GC issue as the total number of returned records count is very large. Being new to slick I am not aware of using streaming. Could someone help in translating below method to stream logic -

```
val res = query.filter { row =>
     (row.category === ServiceConstants.CATEGORY_TYPE.name ) &&
       (row.ftrxDate >= trxDateLowerLimit && row.ftrxDate <= trxDateUpperLimit)}.result
db.run(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on how to stream data from the database in the manual:

https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.2/dbio.html#streaming